# Is it possible to access a mobile's camera from a web app without saving the picture?

Tags: java, image, mobile, web, camera

We are creating an java website for mobile and need to get camera access through the web browser but i do not want the picture to be saved to the storage of the phone. Is this possible?

Comment: Why would the picture be saved to the user's phone. You would have to do something extra to save image to phone, by default it will be in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. there are several comercial applications including surfline's webcam